# SonarQube doesn't find all issues at the same time

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

We face this strange problem that sometimes SonarQube finds certain issues and sometimes it doesn't.

In this [screenshot of some issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRpuG.png) you'll see Sonar found a violation at line 217. However, you see the same violation occuring at line 207, though Sonar did not detect that one!

Furthermore, if you look at the [git blame information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBbOC.png) you'll see that the code was written some months ago, even though SonarQube did not detect it until today (5 hours ago), while we analyze our code base every day.

I couldn't find this issue described anywhere, but I also can't believe that we're the only one experiencing this issue. Did anyone else run into this problem and does anyone have a solution perhaps?

PS: We are currently using SonarQube 5.3 with the C# 4.3 plugin. We experienced the same problems with SonarQube 5.1, and with C# plugin 4.4. Also with different versions of the MSBuild SonarQube Runner.

Comment: Do you see both issues in Visual Studio 2015 using SonarLint?

Comment: Which version of MSBuild are you building the project with for the SonarQube analysis? Version 14 should get you the same results as the one you see in Visual Studio 2015 with SonarLint, and will be more accurate than if you use MSBuild 12. Note that this requires the C# plugin version 4.4, and that version 4.5 is now available and should be used if possible.

Comment: Also make sure your quality profile has rule S1226 enabled

Comment: Finally, if you still experience this issue, please have a look at the SARIF JSON reports (which will be produced only by MSBuild 14): These files contain all detected issues. If you see both issues there but not in SonarQube, we'll know that the problem comes from the import or rendering. If only 1 issues is in the JSON file, the problem is with the analyzer itself.

Comment: Note that the rule S1226 is now disabled by default in the latest SonarLint for Visual Studio version 1.8, and that you will have to enable it explicitly in your ruleset in the IDE

Comment: SonarLint 1.8 in Visual Studio 2015 finds the issues on both lines correctly.
I then upgraded C# plugin to 4.5 MSBuild SonarQube Runner 2.0.
Then, when I ran the analysis again... the result was inversed! The issue at line 217 wasn't found, but this time the issue at line 207 was.

Comment: I can't seem to find any SARIF Json reports. Should those be in the .sonarqube directory in the source directory? We run MsBuild with /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0. We even use C# 6 features.
However, in the build output I see "
Started SonarQube runner
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'."
Why does it auto-detect version 4.0?

Comment: You'll find the SARIF JSON report paths in the `ProjectInfo.xml` files located under `.sonarqube\out\...\ProjectInfo.xml` , it should be set as `<Property Name="sonar.cs.roslyn.reportFilePath">...</Property>`

Comment: How are you launching the MSBuild Runner? AFAIK there shouldn't be any MSBuild auto-detection logic anywhere so I am wondering what is generating this `Started SonarQube runner MSBuild auto-detection` message

Comment: I found the SARIF JSON files which contained the correct information.
In my previous comment I wrote that the detected issues had been reversed, but actually it did detect both issues, but one was hidden because I orginally marked it as "Won't fix". So everything works currently now.
It wasn't like that when I started my question, so the upgrade to the latest C# plugin and the newest MSBuild Scanner must have fixed the issue. Thanks for your time!

Comment: By the way, "MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0'" is still there. We do nothing special: we run NuGet restore, then MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin, then MSBuild on the solution and then MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end.
However, it still seems to use msbuild14 somehow, as it compiles c#6 code and it does output the SARIF Json files, so I'm not concerned about that.

Comment: perfect then :) glad to see the problem solved